# Repairing (possible) earthing/ground issue in computer PSU?

Tags: power-supply, current, computers, grounding, short-circuit

I've got a computer that will no longer power on. It used to be willing to power on quite randomly, and ran fine when it did.

I'm not an electronics savvy person, but i've done a manual check on the pc-motherboard connector voltages, and they seem fine. It's Watt supply limit are also supposedly ok according to an online watt requirements calculator.

I notice a slight tingling if i touch the computer case with i.e the inside of my lower arm where it's thin skin.

This means there is leaking power somewhere? My first thought is that it might somehow come from the area where all the connectors cables exit the PSU.

But i'd like any thoughts on it from someone educated, wether or not it's possible to fix, or even try to fix, before i shell out for a new PSU.

Comment: Not related to your question, but might help you out along the way: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/7986/2241

Comment: @JYelton Surely there must be worse problems with my english. But thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: It's actually not too bad. Good luck with your PSU.

Comment: Do you have the computer plugged into a grounded outlet? The case of the power supply, and therefore, the computer case should be connected to the ground of the power plug. I would check the outlet ground or try plugging into a different outlet.

Comment: @DoxyLover it has been behaving like this even in two different houses, where it would refuse to power on at times, seemingly at random. And not powering on at all these last two days.

And the tingling could be felt using a grounded extension cord (into a grounded outlet) as well i think. (it's so weak it's hard to notice it, so i'll try to measure it to be sure).

The only thing connected together right now, is the motherboard and the PSU, the tingling can be felt still, so i'm assuming it has to be the PSU. But it would be nice to be able to rule out anything else before spending money.

Comment: @all Well, it's most definetly the psu lol, it's even giving out stronger zzap when disconnected from anything else, and even when the main powerswitch is set to 0. I'll give re-assembling the psu's casing a try, and then call it bust if that doesn't help. Sorry for taking your time, and thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell out for a new power supply. It's clearly failing and is connected to your mains power which can kill you. Since we have no idea what is actually wrong, it's best to assume the worst.

Since you admit you're not very electronic savvy, this is probably not a safe place to start.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it's what seems to be the solution. But first I need to know if the problem is a leak on the PSU or the motherboard (or can it leak?).

One question then, if I place the motherboard on an insulated surface, and a leak current can be measured on/from the psu's own casing, then it _must_ be the PSU, right? And if not, and a leak can be measued on/from the connected motherboard, then it _has_ to be the motherboard leaking?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an easy question to answer. It COULD be that the motherboard receptacle is shorting two pins of the connector together. Or any number of other possibilities. I can only say from personal experience that I've never had a motherboard fail electrically. But I have had power supplies fail a few times. Sometimes quite spectacularly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. My previous comment above, disappeared under "show 1 more comment". Anyway, it is the PSU that is leaking, since it gave off quite a stronger feel to the fingertips from it's own casing when disconnected and removed from the pc entirely. So i'll give re-assembling the casing a go, and trashbin the PSU if the problem is still there. I just hope it has not damaged any components, such as brand new ram chips. Thanks